Does weak convergence in $D([0,T),\mathbb{R})$ for all $T>0$ imply convergence in $D([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$
If $X_n(.)$ is a sequence of processes in $D([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$. I am confused whether the following are true.

For every $T>0$, there exists $X^{T}$ in $D([0,T),\mathbb{R})$ such that $X_n$ weakly converges to $X^{T}$ in $D([0,T),\mathbb{R})$. Then does there exist $X$ in $D([0,T),\mathbb{R})$ such that $X_n$ weakly converges to $X$ in $D([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ ?

If suppose there exists $X$ in $D([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$, and $X_n$ weakly converges to $X$ in $D([0,T),\mathbb{R})$. Then does $X_n$ weakly converges to $X$ in $D([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ ?


